# Checking past tenses in a sentence

Tags: tenses

Are the tenses in this sentence correct?

*Oggi ho visto la mia amica Amanda che non vedevo da molto tempo.*

Would this version be better?

*Oggi ho visto la mia amica Amanda che non avevo visto da molto tempo.*

Comment: The first sentence is ok. The second one sounds too English: a native wouldn't use it, but nonetheless everyone would understand you anyway. If the person you're talking to knows Amanda, or if s(he) knows that you have a friend called Amanda, it would be more natural to say "Oggi ho visto Amanda... non la vedevo da un sacco (di tempo)"